# Pbm marshaling XML with classes generated via JAXB2

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

today is one day I think I'll become crazy.

I would like to generate some code to be able to mashshall/unmarshall XML files.
I'm starting with an XSD that I pass to JAXB2 to generate Java classes via a maven module => It's OK.

Then I'm using those generated classes to make a first test to create a basic XML file but I've got the following error : Impossible to serialize type "com.xxx.xxx.AudioService" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

```
public static void marshal() throws JAXBException, IOException {
        AudioService audioService = new AudioService();
        
        audioService.setName("TTS1");
        audioService.setEngineClass("Toto");
        
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AudioService.class);
        Marshaller mar= context.createMarshaller();
        mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        mar.marshal(audioService, new File("./test.xml"));
    }
```

But my generated  class AudioService looks to :

```
package com.xxx.xxx;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


@XmlRootElement(name = "audio-service")
public class AudioService {

    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    protected List<AudioService.Property> properties;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected AudioService.Tts tts;
```

Does anybody have an idea why this error is thrown as everything seems ok ?

Note it's runing under java 17,
javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api = 2.3.1
jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api=4.0.0

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to build the instance with required attributes `@XmlElement(required = true)`

Comment: Need to see the beginning of XML file.  root tag should be "audio-service" and it is case sensitive.  The issue could be the namespace needs to be defined in class definition.

Comment: Here's a small stand-alone sample project [README](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/animal/README.md) and [ZIP](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-animal-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) that uses `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0`, `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.2` and [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme). It should be easy to replace the sample schema with your schema to see if it helps to use the latest JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, It gives me the idea to check my dependencies.
Finally I've found the pbm in the pom i had mixed dependencies with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency> I had mix import with :
```

And

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Since I've removed javax.xml.bind packages It's now resolved !

Thanks again